# SingleSignOn with snowflake is giving saml error 390191 - USERNAMES_MISMATCH

Tags: authentication, adfs, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to login to snowflake using ADFS but getting the above error, what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue to be the name mismatch and solved the issue

Comment: Do you mind marking this as the answer, there are few tools that can be used to troubleshoot this, how did you resolve this? What about updating https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Configuring-your-IDP-to-Snowflake-by-providing-required-properties-in-a-SAML-Response with that ;)

Comment: I've run the query select *
from table(information_schema.login_history_by_user('username'))
I found the reason for connection failure and SAML error code
Basically LOGIN_NAME in user table should match the username we are sending in connection string

Answer (score 0):

There must a specific attribute which is required in the token for snowflake to work.
Take a fiddler trace and check if the required claim is coming in the token or not.
Watch this to know the claims mapping - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsjhoE-M_yk

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture the SAML response using the SAML tracer browser extension and see the NameID. You can try to set the same NameID as login_name for the snowflake user at the snowflake side.

For example- If SAML response shows the NameID as abc@xyz.com then you can try to set login_name as "abc@xyz.com" (alter user username set login_name="abc@xyz.com"). You can do this for a test user and see if it helps.

SAML response snippet:

```
<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"><abc@xyz.com></NameID>
```